# Reload Visualforce page on session lost

Tags: visualforce, exception, session

Im trying to reload a Visualforce page when session is lost, due to another login, and sessionId created in a different browser tab. 
I have code that makes constant calls to the controller methods, when the sessionId is no longer valid, this message shows up in the console:

```
Visualforce Remoting Exception: Remoting request invalid for your session.  Refresh page and re-submit request {statusCode: 402, type: "exception", ref: false, action: "Unknown", method: "Unknown",tid: 84}
```

This is printed by a VFRemote.js method

How should i handle this exception to be able to reload the page